# Android Calendar Dialog Like Google Timeline Calendar

Tags: android, android-calendar

I would like to add a calendar in my android app where user can see their daily orders, just like google day visits timeline calendar dialog [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/786ha.jpg). Any sample project or guideline is appreciated.

Expecting a library like Google Day visits Calendar